# CRTL-ALT-F1 Keys not Recognized with 16.04

Tags: 16.04, keyboard, shortcut-keys, shortcuts, single-user

When I press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> ubuntu does not do anything. I have had the same problem with a lot of keyboard shortcuts(although I think those are GNOME shortcuts, unlike this one), particularly ones involving <kbd>CTRL</kbd>.

I have a macbook pro with a USB keyboard(with a mac layout) but I have also tried with the native keyboard. Here is what I get from the Keyboard Layout Chart in the unity bar with the USB keyboard.

Keyboard Layout Chart with English(UK, macintosh for <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>):

[image]

But for <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> I get a response

Keyboard Layout Chart with English(UK, macintosh for <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>):

[image]

I had heard in my research into the issue that <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>, ...<kbd>F3</kbd> and ...<kbd>F7</kbd> were "reserved" as well, so I am not sure why all of these seem to be input to the system but appear to be ignored.

Any help would be greatly appreciated as full-screen games can be pain.